# How can I implement a android app which is developed with kotlin in Android studio with my back end in spring boot?

Tags: angular, spring, kotlin, boot

I have a backend side with spring boot I used restfull and websockts as protocolos, I also have a angular front side which works well.
My next step is that Im going to develop a mobile app with kotlin, is it posible or not? because I need all of my backend resources in the mobile version of the app.

Also at the beginnign i want to use apache cordova but IDK.

Right now im thinking solutions for the mobile side, the front and end its working.